# Problems with Java Arrays.sort() on sub-arrays -- is this a bug?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, sub-array

I have noticed odd behavior when using Java Arrays.sort() on sub-arrays.  Here is a demo program.  Is this a bug in Java?

```
package sorted_subsegments;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class sortTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int A[] = {3, 2, 1};
        System.out.format("A: %s\n", Arrays.toString(A));
        Arrays.sort(A, 0, 1);
        System.out.format(" after sub array sort on A: %s\n", Arrays.toString(A));
        System.out.println("Should be A: [2, 3, 1]");
        Arrays.sort(A);
        System.out.format(" whole array sort on A: %s\n", Arrays.toString(A));
    }
}
```

Comment: And the result is?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Have you read [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-int-int-)? "toIndex - the index of the last element, ***exclusive***, to be sorted"

Comment: Java is already more than 20 years old, and this method has existed since the beginning - you can be quite sure that it does not contain a bug that would be so obvious.

Comment: @assylias thank-you.  I have been too much late night programming to read the doc correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Javadoc

> fromIndex - the index of the first element, inclusive, to be sorted
>
> toIndex - the index of the last element, ***exclusive***, to be sorted

The second index (`toIndex`) is NOT included in the range to be sorted.

So, in your example

```
Arrays.sort(A, 0, 1);
```

you are sorting only element [0] of the array, which does nothing.